# React - Filter list by gender or age

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of users with name, gender, age, etc from the following api: [https://gorest.co.in/public-api/users]. At the moment I can filter by `gender === female`, but doesn't work when I filter for `gender === male`.

Also, I try to filter the list of users by age. I get the date of birth and sorted afterwards, but it doesn't seem enough.

I have a [LIVE EXAMPLE HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-cdn-n9mpm)

Here is the code:

```js
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default class UserList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      list: [],
      search: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getList();
  }

  /* get users list */
  getList = async () => {
    const api = 'https://gorest.co.in/public-api/users?_format=json&access-token=3qIi1MDfD-GXqOSwEHHLH73Y3UitdaFKyVm_';

    await axios
      .get(api)
      .then(response => {
        const list = response.data.result;
        this.setState({
          list,
          isLoading: false
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  /* handler for search bar */
  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      search: e.target.value
    });
  };

  filterGender = gender => {
    const lowerCaseGender = gender.toLowerCase();
    const filteredGender = this.state.list.filter(
      user => user.gender.toLowerCase().indexOf(lowerCaseGender) !== -1
    );

    this.setState({ list: filteredGender }, () => console.log(this.state.list));
  };

  filterAge = () => {
    const ageList = this.state.list.map(age => {
      return age.dob;
    });

    const filteredAge = this.state.list.filter(
      e => e.dob.indexOf(ageList) !== -1
    );

    this.setState({ list: filteredAge }, () => console.log(this.state.list));
  };

  render() {
    let style = {
      display: "grid",
      gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr))",
      padding: "1rem",
      gridGap: "1rem 1rem"
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <input
          placeholder="Search for a user..."
          onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}
        />
        <button onClick={() => this.filterGender("male")}>Male</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.filterGender("female")}>Female</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.filterAge()}>Age</button>
        <ul style={style}>
          {this.state.list.map(user => {
            return (
              <li key={user.id}>
                <div>
                  <img className="thumb" alt="" src={user._links.avatar.href} />
                </div>

                <div className="userInfo">
                  <p>
                    {user.first_name} {user.last_name}
                  </p>
                </div>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: The index of matches both cases. Female includes male

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in your code.

**Here I have updated your code.

https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-swartz-iu3qp**

**Problem 1:** use of `indexOf` in **filterGender** function

**Solution 1:** directly compare the gender instead of `indexOf`

```
const filteredGender = this.list.filter(
    user => user.gender.toLowerCase() === lowerCaseGender
);
```

**Problem 2:** You are filtering records from the `this.state.list` variable and then update it in same `state` variable.

**Solution 2:** Use another variable `this.list` in `constructor` and use it to filter the records.

Define variable in `constructor`

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      list: [],
      search: ""
    };
    this.list = []; // define new list here...
  }
```

You have to assign upcoming list to `this.list` variable in **getList** function

```
this.list = response.data.result;
```

**`getList` function should be look like below.**

```
getList = async () => {
    const api =
      "https://gorest.co.in/public-api/users?_format=json&access-token=3qIi1MDfD-GXqOSwEHHLH73Y3UitdaFKyVm_";

    await axios
      .get(api)
      .then(response => {
        this.list = response.data.result; // assign list in variable
        this.setState({
          list:this.list,
          isLoading: false
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

Now you have to update both filter function as below. Instead of `this.state.list` use `this.list`.

```
filterGender = gender => {
    const lowerCaseGender = gender.toLowerCase();
    const filteredGender = this.list.filter(
      user => user.gender.toLowerCase() === lowerCaseGender
    );

    this.setState({ list: filteredGender }, () => console.log(this.state.list));
  };

  filterAge = () => {
    const ageList = this.list.map(age => {
      return age.dob;
    });

    const filteredAge = this.list.filter(
      e => e.dob.indexOf(ageList) !== -1
    );

    this.setState({ list: filteredAge }, () => console.log(this.state.list));
  };
```

Hope this will work for you!

Answer (score 1):

The condition you are using,

```
user.gender.toLowerCase().indexOf(lowerCaseGender) !== -1
```

is matching `male` in `female` due to `indexOf`.

You should do this,

```
const filteredGender = this.state.list.filter(
      user => user.gender.toLowerCase() === lowerCaseGender
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Full working demo with corrected code in same environment

- https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-carson-6zilx

**Gender**

> **Issue** - `indexOf` function use does't achieves anything.
>
> **Resolution** -:
>
> Using simple `Array.filter` with gender equality.
>
> This function needs to be changed for gender filter -:
>
> ```
>   filterGender = gender => {
>     const filteredGender = this.state.list.filter(
>       user => user.gender.toLowerCase() === gender
>     );
>     this.setState({ list: filteredGender }, () => console.log(this.state.list));
>   };
> ```

**Age**

> **Issue** - Filtering won't be helpful to sort data.
>
> **Resolution** -:
>
> Using `Array.sort` and adding a comparator function.
>
> This function needs to be changed for age sorting -:
>
> ```
>   filterAge = () => {
>     const filteredAge = this.state.list.sort(function(a, b) {
>       return new Date(b.dob) - new Date(a.dob);
>     });
>
>     this.setState({ list: filteredAge }, () => console.log(this.state.list));
>   };
> ```

Comment: Thank you! Your answear was very hepful! @Abhisar Tripathi